# What is the fully-convolutional model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, computer-vision, caffe

What is the fully-convolutional model?

Is fully-convolutional model a model that has only convolutional layers (with Batch-norm and Activation) and has not any: max-pool, fully-connected, and other layers?

If it is true, then why Yolo v2 neural network for object detection is named Fully-Convolutional model if it uses Max-pool layers: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.08242v1.pdf

> Table 2: The path from YOLO to YOLOv2. Most of the listed design
>   decisions lead to significant increases in mAP. Two  exceptions are
>   **switching to a fully convolutional network** with anchor boxes and using the new network.

[image]

---

Also why Fully Convolutional Networks for Semantic Segmentation is named Fully Convolutional if it has Max-pool layers: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, a network with CNN with no Fully connected layers is termed as Fully Convolutional Network(FCN). It can include any type of pooling layers, batch norm, dropouts etc.